# vetores python,help?

Tags: python, array

Não sei aonde estou errando,eu fiz tudo direitinho ,mas apareceu o erro e não sei o que fazer,eu sou novata de programção.

Faça um programa que leia um vetor vet de 20 números inteiros. O programa deve gerar, a partir do vetor lido, um outro vetor pos que contenha apenas os valores inteiros positivos de vet. A partir do vetor pos, deve ser gerado um outro vetor semdup que contenha apenas uma ocorrência de cada valor de pos.

```
pos = []
semdup = []
vet = (input('Entre com 20 números inteiros separados por espaço: ')).split()
if len(vet) != 20:
  print('Quantidade de números digitados diferentes de 20!')
  vet = (input('Entre com os números inteiros separados por espaço: ')).split()
for i in range(20):
  vet[i] = int(vet[i])
print('vet = ',vet)
for i in range(0,20):
  if vet[i] >= 0:
    pos.append(vet[i])
print('pos = ',pos)
semdup = sorted(set(pos))
print('semdup = ',semdup)
```

Comment: Ola, qual erro apareceu quando você rodou o seu programa? Eu testei ele e pareceu funcionar direito para mim

Comment: Camila, bom dia! Como o Flavio disse seu código funciona. Pode ser que esteja com alguma indentação errada. Abraço!

Comment: Sempre é bom colocar as mensagens de erro exibidas pelo compilador. De uma lida no [Checklist de perguntas do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8496/checklist-de-perguntas-do-stack-overflow?cb=1).

Answer (score 1):

Nesta questão você precisa seguir uma lógica bem definida. Esta lógica deve seguir as seguintes etapas:

1. Implementar um vetor com 20 elementos;
2. Montar outro vetor com apenas valores positivos do primeiro vetor;
3. Montar outro vetor com apenas valores positivos e sem repetições do primeiro vetor;
4. Exibir os três vetores.

Existe diversas formas de você implementar o vetor. Você pode montar o vetor com o laço de repetição **for**, **while**, **list compherensio** ou com a função **map**.

Depois de ter implementado o vetor. Você precisa montar outro vetor com apenas os valores positivos e outro vetor com apenas valores positivos e sem repetições. Em seguida, exibir os respectivos vetores.

Uma das formas de se implementar um código que satisfaça esta lógica é:

```
vet = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores: ').split()))

pos = list()
semdup = list()
for i in vet:
    if i > 0:
        pos.append(i)
        if i not in semdup:
            semdup.append(i)

print(f'O vetor "vet" é: {vet}')
print(f'O vetor "pos" é: {pos}')
print(f'O vetor "semdup" é: {semdup}')
```

Quando executamos este código, recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite os valores:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos os 20** valores, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e, pressionar `ENTER`.

A partir deste momento o código irá montar uma lista com todos os valores digitados. Posteriormente o laço de repetição **for** percorrerá todo o vetor `vet` e com ajuda do **1º bloco if**, será verificado se cada valor da respectiva interação é maior que **0**. Caso positivo, este valor será adicionado ao vetor **pos**. Em seguida, o **2º bloco if** verificará se o respectivo valor da interação não existe no vetor **semdup**. Caso este valor não exista no vetor **semdup**, o mesmo será adicionado ao vetor **semdup**.

Depois de ter realizado estas operações os vetores **vet**, **pos** e **semdup** são exibidos.

**Observação:**

Neste código utilizei apenas um laço de repetição **for**. Com isso, podemos melhor otimizar bastante a execução do código.

**Vamos testa o código**

Ao executar o código, recebemos a mensagem: `Digite os valores:` . Neste momento devemos digitar os 20 valores, na mesma linha, separados por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`. Então digitamos...

```
-4 2 -3 6 6 7 7 -8 9 -10 11 -11 13 13 13 14 -15 18 19 20
```

...e pressionamos `enter`.

Em seguida, o código realizará todas as operações e nos fornecerá a seguinte saída:

```
O vetor "vet" é: [-4, 2, -3, 6, 6, 7, 7, -8, 9, -10, 11, -11, 13, 13, 13, 14, -15, 18, 19, 20]
O vetor "pos" é: [2, 6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 11, 13, 13, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20]
O vetor "semdup" é: [2, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Aviso**: o programa a seguir não faz verificações quanto ao número de elementos inseridos ou faz qualquer validação sobre os mesmos.

O interpretador *Python* vem com a função embutida [`filter(func, iteravel)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#filter) que constrói um iterador a partir dos elementos de um iterável cujo os quais a função passada no parâmetro `func` retorna verdadeiro:

```
vet = map(int, input('Digite os valores: ').split())

#A função anônima diz a filter, se o elemento de vet for maior ou igual a zero esse 
#fará parte do resultado. 
pos = list(filter(lambda x: x>=0, vet))

print(pos)
```

Leitura sugerida [Expressões Lambda](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions).